# Show Data in admin side. Magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, backend

I'm showing data in admin side like 
[image]

and its code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_edit.makeanoffer_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_edit.makeanoffer_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Make An Offer</item>
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_edit</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
         <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="accept" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\AcceptButton</item>
            <item name="reject" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Block\Adminhtml\MakeAnOffer\Edit\RejectButton</item>      
        </item>        
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="makeanoffer_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PME\MakeAnOffer\Model\MakeAnOffer\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="makeanoffer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="product_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Product Name:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Name:</item>  
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Email:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="pnumber">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer PhoneNo:</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">makeanoffer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

but I want to show this data like

[image]

Now How can I change my ui_component view like this?

Comment: There is no default table ui component still the magento2.3.1. So either you have to use custom css for it or block method

Comment: how can I use custom *CSS* on `xml` file?

Comment: you can add in layout file

Answer (score 0):

You may try the process described below but to follow the process you need to create an admin theme.

**step 1 )** Create an Admin Theme. You can check this  [Create an admin theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html).

I assume you created an admin theme with name "**MyCompany_mytheme**"

**step 2 )** Create an HTML template file input-custom.html under  YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/adminhtml/MyCompany/mytheme/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/element for input UI element.

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<input class="admin__control-text" readonly style="background-color: #fff;border-color: #fff;color:#000000;cursor: not-allowed;opacity: 1" type="text"
    data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,            
            maxlength: 255
    }"/>
```

**Note:** Please remove inline CSS and try to use CSS class

**step 3)** Update your UI component XML to set new HTML template, mark the field as read-only (but not disable) for Input field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
-------------------
-------------------
<field name="pnumber">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     ------------------
                     ------------------
                   <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>                    
                   <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input-custom</item>                    
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> 
-------------
</form>
```

**Please Note :**
item "disabled"    =  False [since we make it readonly from custom template]
item "elementTmpl" =  ui/form/element/input-custom [Custom Template path for input field UI]

**step 4)** Flush Magento cache

[image]